# @autorelease and loops

Tags: objective-c, loops, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

Assume I have a code like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
  for(int i = 0; i < relatedSlideDecks.count; i++) {
    MyClass *myObject = [MyClass new];
    ... something happens here
    [myObject release];
  {
}
```

do I still need that `[myObject release];`? Or will it be autoreleased because of `@autoreleasepool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still a requirement to release `myObject` because the `@autoreleasepool` block does not change the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/), which state that you must relinquish ownership of objects you own, and you own `myObject`. The one thing you can't do is use an object that was autoreleased within an `@autoreleasepool` block outside of that block. It is useful if you have a small section of your program that may create a lot of autoreleased objects that need to be released as soon as possible rather than until the main autorelease pool is drained.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ARC it shouldn't be necessary at all.

Otherwise you need to call that release method.

The only thing that ensures that @autoreleasepool block is that once your code executes past it, any object with an autorelease call, will get it's release call.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you still need that `[myObject release]`. The presence of `@autoreleasepool` doesn't cause objects to magically get autoreleased. It just causes objects that *are* autoreleased to be cleaned up when the autorelease pool drains. You can read more at the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).